# Thymeleaf Select Option Value not accepting two letter codes for US states NE, OR

Tags: thymeleaf

Thymeleaf is unable to parse "NE" for Nebraska and "OR" for Oregon in the following select form control (are they perhaps reserved keywords NE="not equals", OR="or"?). How to escape this if indeed they are reserved?  Trying to avoid hard-coding this list in controller.  This is a common use-case, has anyone determined best practice to list US state codes without tripping up expression languages?

```
   <select class="form-control" th:field="*{state}" id="exampleSelect1">
    <option th:value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option th:value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option th:value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option th:value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <!-- and so on -->
    <!--  option th:value="NE">Nebraska</option -->
    <option th:value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option th:value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <!-- and so on -->
    <option th:value="TX" selected=selected>Texas</option>
    <option th:value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option th:value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option th:value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option th:value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option th:value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option th:value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option th:value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
```

Stacktrace is as follows (for Oregon):

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "OR" (address-form)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:238)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:79)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:40)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(AbstractStandardSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:65)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringValueAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(SpringValueAttrProcessor.java:71)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedAttributeValues(AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:62)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1524)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` is reserved by thymeleaf.

so you can do below

```
<option th:value="'OR'">Oregon</option>
```

or

```
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
```